# Ubuntu problems

Tags: 13.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10, I was running Winows XP previously. My Ubuntu is unable to pick up my internet and my Wi-Fi is not working. Ubuntu is my sole operating system right now, but I really need to get rid of it. If I was to put in a Windows 7 install disk, do you think I could get Windows running again on my laptop? And if so, how do I go about getting Windows 7 working?

Comment: Is your wireless turned on? What wireless card are you using? Did the Wireless worked earlier?

Comment: If your computer is powerful enough to wake Windows 7 work, and if you have a valid Windows 7 CD key, you can install it without problem. Have you tried if installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS solve your wifi problem?

Comment: A few comments, this site is for Ubuntu support. You will need to purchase windows 7 and track down any drivers you need. If you wish to use Ubuntu, I suggest you go with 14.04, 13.10 is a few months from end of life and a more recent version of Ubuntu is more likely to support your hardware.

Comment: Do you want to try and fix your wifi, or do you want to re-install Windows 7?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply. I was eventually able to get Windows XP working. Thanks for all the help.